# How to set Manage Stock to "NO" in Magento 2.1 backend for all Store Views?

Tags: magento2

How can I set Manage Stock to "NO" in Magento 2.1 as a Config Setting (system value) from the backend?

By Config Setting I mean that the "NO" value should be the system value (preset) when creating a new prodcut in any Store View.

Answer (score -1):

Go to *Admin Configuration-Catalog-Inventory-Product Stock Option*, you can see config Manage Stock
[image]

Comment: Thank you MageX, but this one I am aware of. What I mean is: how to change the system value to "No" from the backend. With your suggestion, the system value will still be "Yes".